# Lost all tags and username changed on profile

Tags: support, user-accounts

I woke up this morning to find that my username had been changed (looks like to my google account username) and I lost all my tags. How did this happen? I have always been logging in with my facebook account. Furthermore, I woke up to find that my inbox was filled with 48 messages saying things like

> > "You have earned this badge for"....

Also, it seems that I am an entirely new user. I was user #5783 and now I am #38158. Can someone explain what's happening please?

Thanks.

I have changed my username back to what it was before I went to bed last night.

Comment: Bizarre! $\colon)$

Comment: @AsafKaragila Amazingly I have now a new ID.....

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE: To keep things interesting, I brought this up to the SE gods. After a period of time, we learned something: There are trusted openID sources, like facebook and gmail, that easily associate with your MSE user credentials. You can have different MSE accounts with different associations. But if you have two different accounts, **and** they have the same email address, there is an automerge functionality, so that the multiple users may be automatically merged into each other.

Something to this effect happened here.

Comment: Hum. How much verification do they do of those email addresses, I wonder? I wouldn't want people to be able to auto-hijack my account simply by creating another one and claiming my email address as their own.

Comment: I don't know where to report this, so I'm doing it here. Ben's meta users don't seem to be affected by this magic merging. Here's the old one: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/5783/benjalim

Comment: @Henning: That's a very good point. So I tested it by attempting to create the user mixedmathHijacker with the same email as my account. When I added a gmail account, gmail asked me to verify by clicking on the email (as we so often see). So it seems to me that one can't hijack your account without first hijacking your email.

Comment: @Henning: that's the point of only accepting these from providers we trust - as long as Google, Yahoo, Facebook and Stack Exchange's own [OpenID](https://openid.stackexchange.com/) are validating emails properly, we can be sure you're the person your provider says you are. Similarly, we ignore any emails coming from Joe's House of Shady OpenIDs.

Comment: BTW: this is the correct answer. Maintaining two separate accounts on the same site is *possible*, but not well supported - if you happen to log into both with the same (or equivalent, as described above) credentials, they'll be automatically merged.

Comment: @Shog9: Can one opt out of trusting Facebook? Years ago I created an account there with a low-security password that I don't remember anymore -- and don't really care about -- but didn't expect to be useful for breaking into my stuff everywhere else on the web ...

Comment: @Henning: if your email is still associated with it, you can recover access to the account and either update the password or delete the account (or better yet, both). You should probably do this for reasons beyond just protecting access to your SE account.

Comment: @Henning, you can also remove the Facebook OpenID from your MSE profile and that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

One of the SE moderators appears to have merged your account with <strike>Jarod Alper</strike>somebody else's. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Jarod Alper does not have a math.se page but a mathoverflow page. Is this due to the fact that MO and Math.SE are merging or something?

Comment: A check reveals that my mathoverflow page (here)[http://mathoverflow.net/users/21278/benjalim] has not been merged with his.

Comment: @Ben: he doesn't have a math.SE page because your accounts have been merged (your page is both of your pages!). math.SE is (currently) completely separate from MO; accounts on one have nothing to do with accounts on the other.

Comment: It might have to do with the fact that Ben's profile links to Jarod's home page (already the old one did, and so does the MO profile).

Comment: @t.b.: Oh. I was not aware of this. (That's very confusing.) In that case, I have no idea who Ben has been merged with.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think I know who I have been merged with. In the usual case I have always been logging in with my facebook account. However one day I accidentally clicked on the google logo when logging in and a new account was created. The name of that account was the same as the one that I saw this morning when I woke up. Perhaps it was merged with that one.

Comment: @BenjaLim This will not help with your Kafkaesque situation, but I think the link to Jarod's page could be placed with his name: as in "Matrix Lie groups and representation theory - [Jarod Alper](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~jarod/)". Chances are, fewer people will be confused by the link then.

Comment: @LVK Besides I think it is quite obvious from my Math.SE front page that I am not Jarod Alper. I linked to his page because he is my lecturer, I am not trying to impersonate anyone.

Comment: @BenjaLim: I don't think that is obvious at all. The natural interpretation of a "website" link in a user profile, without further qualification, is that the link will take you to the user's personal website. I don't think you should be using that field to link to a personal website that is not yours.

Comment: We don't use the *website* for validating or merging accounts. Since that information is publicly visible, it would be trivial to steal access to someone else's account if we did!

Comment: @BenjaLim of course you're not trying to impersonate, and your *about me* section points out you're 2nd year undergraduate, but please remember that the *website* entry (along with *location* & *age*) is located under the "*bio*" section of the profile.